# Window load inside self invoking jQuery plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery plugin code to do something on window load or scroll:

Note: I simplified the code for the example.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    $.scrollFn = function (el, options) {
       var base = this;

        // jQuery and DOM of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Cached
        base.$win = $(window);
        base.$doc = $(document);

        // Initialize
        base.init = function () {
          base.options = $.extend({}, $.scrollFn.defaultOptions, options);
        };

        // Scroll handler
        base.scrollHandler = function () {
           console.log('scrolled or loaded');
           console.log(base.options.exampleOption);
        };

        // On scroll and load
        base.$win.on('scroll load', base.scrollHandler);
    };

    $.scrollFn.defaultOptions = {
      exampleOption: "Test"
    };

    $.fn.scrollFn = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            (new $.scrollFn(this, options));
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

And in another JS I am initializing the scroll function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.example').scrollFn({
    exampleOption: "Hello world"
  });
});
```

The issue: It is picking up window scroll but not load. When the window loads I do not see the console return `scrolled or loaded`. It shows only when I scroll.

How can I make load work as well?

I tried (inside scrollFn):

```
$(window).on('scroll load', base.scrollHandler);

base.$doc.on('scroll load', base.scrollHandler);

$(document).ready(function() {
 base.$win.on('scroll load', base.scrollHandler);
});
```

They do not work.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` occurs *after* the window load event, so any code listening for that event will not receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to simply add `base.scrollHandler` in the init function. I will except any other answer providing more info or a better solution if possible.